# How do I invoke a descendant's implementation when I call a method on a base class?

Tags: delphi, inheritance

My top level class is `TBaseDB`, which has a descendant `TCommonDB` (, and `TCommonDB` will have  multiple descendants, like `TProdDB` and `TDevDB`).

Let's create a function in *each* class definition, called `Test1`. For now, all it does is a `ShowMessage('Some literal')` just to show me what code is being executed.

I don't know the class type until runtime. I want to have common code, but different behavior.

What I want is something like this:

```
var
  MyObj: TBaseDB;
begin        
  //pseudo-code...
  if RadioButton1.Checked then
    MyObj := TBaseDB.Create
  else
    MyObj := TCommonDB.create;
  MyObj.Test1;    
end;
```

I can't seem to get this to work, and I imagine it is in my class definition. How should `Test1` be defined so that:

1. I can declare my variable as `TBaseDB`,
2. the created class can be either `TBaseDB` or `TCommonDB`, and
3. the *proper* `Test` procedure will be called depending on the instance being a `TBaseDB` or `TCommonDB`?

Comment: Declare Test1 as virtual, and override it in descendants

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TFruit = class
  public
    procedure ShowMessage; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TApple = class(TFruit)
  public
    procedure ShowMessage; override;
  end;

  TOrange = class(TFruit)
  public
    procedure ShowMessage; override;
  end;


{ TApple }

procedure TApple.ShowMessage;
begin
  Writeln('I''m an apple!');
end;

{ TOrange }

procedure TOrange.ShowMessage;
begin
  Writeln('I''m an orange!');
end;

var
  fruit: TFruit;

begin

  fruit := TApple.Create;

  fruit.ShowMessage;

  Writeln('Press Enter to continue.');
  Readln;

end.
```

The keyword `abstract` allows you to have no implementation at all in the base class. You can also, however, have an implementation there as well:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TFruit = class
  public
    procedure ShowMessage; virtual;
  end;

  TApple = class(TFruit)
  public
    procedure ShowMessage; override;
  end;

  TOrange = class(TFruit)
  public
    procedure ShowMessage; override;
  end;


{ TFruit }

procedure TFruit.ShowMessage;
begin
  Writeln('I''m a fruit.');
end;

{ TApple }

procedure TApple.ShowMessage;
begin
  inherited;
  Writeln('I''m an apple!');
end;

{ TOrange }

procedure TOrange.ShowMessage;
begin
  inherited;
  Writeln('I''m an orange!');
end;

var
  fruit: TFruit;

begin

  fruit := TApple.Create;

  fruit.ShowMessage;

  Writeln('Press Enter to continue.');
  Readln;

end.
```

**Exercises:**

1. In each case, what happens if you create an instance of `TFruit`?
2. In the second case, what does `inherited` in `TApple.ShowMessage` and `TOrange.ShowMessage` mean? Do they need to be at the top of the procedures? What happens if you omit them?

Comment: The combination of virtual in the ancestor, and override in the descendant was what I was missing.  That did what I wanted.  As an FYI, you state that ABSTRACT can have an implementation.  When I tried this, I get the error 'No definition for abstract method 'Test1' allowed. This may be specific to Delphi 2010...  Thanks for the great example!

Comment: @user, read it carefully ;-) Andreas wrote, *"the keyword abstract allows you to have no implementation at all"* and then mentioned, that you can have there an implementation (if you omit the `abstract` keyword).

Comment: Fair enough...  I read 'allows' to mean optionality, but really, abstract FORCES no implementation.  Is that a more accurate statement?

Comment: @user1009073: Well, it is certainly a correct statement, but I'm not sure I'd say it's 'more accurate' than my original one! :)